# change date from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have problem with conversion date, i have data with format date.
so here my code:

```
<?php echo row->start_date;?>
```

output:

```
2016-10-24
```

so I want output like this:

```
october,23 2016.

2016,october 23
```

how to change default date database like above?

Comment: Please do a search either google or here before asking a question. Many many questions already have very good answers

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
$start_date = '2016-10-24';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $start_date);
echo $date->format('F, d Y'); #october,24 2016

$start_date = '2016-10-24';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $start_date);
echo $date->format('Y, F d'); #2016,october 24
```